# Get Model State data in java script from error response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-core

I have a controller action in ASP.Net Core that is returning a `BadRequest` with some model state. I want to flatten the validation messages into a single array within my Angular promise error handler. I'm not sure how to go about doing it though.

This is how I am returning the `BadRequest` in my Web API controller action.

```
return base.BadRequest(base.ModelState);
```

Then in my Angular controller, I have an error handler like this for now.

```
(function () {
    angular.module('app')
        .controller('AccountCreationController', AccountCreationController);

    function AccountCreationController(AccountCreationService) {
        var viewModel = this;
        viewModel.accountSetup = AccountCreationService.getAccountTypes();
        viewModel.create = create;
        viewModel.errors = new Array();

        function create(user) {
            var result = AccountCreationService.createAccount(user).$promise.then(function (response) {
                var x = response;
            },
            function (error) {
                // iterate over each key in the key/value pair.
                for (var key in error.data) {
                    // iterate over each element in the data[key] array of validation messages
                    for (var e in error.data[key]) {
                        errors.push(e);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

The `error` object has a `data` property on it, that contains the model state array. The model looks like this:

[image]

I can get access to the array of validation messages by typing `error.data["1"]` into the Chrome console, and I can get the message shown in the screenshot with `error.data["1"][0]`. However, when I try to iterate over the data property to pull out the errors into a flattened array, the array is empty. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here (new to JS) - I was iterating over each key in the `data` property, then iterating over each value in the array held for that key.

What am I supposed to do in order to get the underlying array of messages out?

**edit**

If I run the for loop in the Chrome console, I get the following output

```
var errors = new Array();
for (var key in error.data) {
    for (var e in error.data[key]) {
        console.log(key + ":" + e[0]);
    }
}
```

> 1:0

Comment: [Avoid](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3010848/758991) the `for..in` for iterating over array. Also you can not iterate at all here. Just use `errors = errors.concat(error.data[key])`

Comment: had a similiar question to yours here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33545909/displaying-invalid-modelstate-in-web-api-via-jquery-ajax only difference is I was using knockout instead of angular

Comment: @djxak Like `for(var key in error.data) { viewModel.errors.concat(error.data[key])}` ? That doesn't yield an array with any values. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: No. The `concat` doesn't change the array. It creates a new array. So it should be `for(var key in error.data) { viewModel.errors = viewModel.errors.concat(error.data[key])}`

Comment: Also note: in your origina question you push strings to the `errors` variable, but actually your variable is defined as `viewModel.errors`. About your **edit**: the `e` is the key name, or array index in this case, so `e[0]` is pointless. use `error.data[key][e]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You `push` strings into the `errors` variable, but actually your variable is defined as `viewModel.errors`.
2. Avoid the `for..in` loop for iterating over array. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3010848/758991) for more details why.
3. If you after all use `for..in` loop, the `e` variable will be an array index, not a value. So you should use `viewModel.errors.push(error.data[key][e]);` instead if `errors.push(e)`.
4. Because your errors array already is array of plain strings, you can avoid inner loop at all here. Just use `viewModel.errors = viewModel.errors.concat(error.data[key])`.

Comment: That worked great! Also appreciate the correction on my usage of `e`. I didn't realize it was giving me back an index - which makes sense now that I look at it.

Answer (score -1):

Use this to access the validation messages

```
error.data[1].0
```

Comment: How do I do that recursively though? I want to take all validation messages and stuff them into a single array. Each Key/Value pair represents an array of messages. As mentioned in my OP, I can access them directly like you show, within the console. My foreach loop though doesn't have the expected result

Comment: sure after solving your problem I will update the answer.. The point is I need to see the data binding into the objects for every error.

Comment: I did. Your answer doesn't give me what the question asked. My OP specifically mentioned I could get the data using your approach via the console, but needed a way to flatten each array in the Key/Value pair without hard-coded key/indexes. Your answer just duplicates what I already tried and doesn't give the desired result